# Celery, uvicorn and FastAPI

Tags: python, api, celery, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a FastAPI api code that is executed using uvicorn. Now I want to add a queu system, and I think Celery and Flower can be great tools for me since my api has some endpoints that uses a lot CPU and take some seconds in answering. However, I have a couple of questions about the addition of Celery:

1. Does Celery substitute Uvicorn? Do I need it any more? I cannot see any example on the website where they consider uvicorn too, and when you execute the Celery seems to do not need it...
2. I have read a lot about using Celery for creating a queu for FastAPI. However, you can manage a queue in FastAPI without using Celery. What's better? and why?

Comment: 1. uvicorn is an ASGI compatible web server. Celery is a task queue. They do orthogonal different things. 2. Celery is out-of-process, letting FastAPI handle what's relevant for the web request itself and handing off the long running process to a proper queue system. Whether the complexity is necessary or "better" depends on your problem at hand.

Comment: That's what I thought. So it is still necessary an ASGI. I'm saying this because I see people starting Celery -A celery_tasks worker But I do not see that they then init the fastapi from uvicorn for instance...

Comment: That would depend on the project layout; you usually wouldn't start the celery workers themselves from FastAPI or uvicorn, only hand off the tasks that should be performed. If you have a resource that you've followed it'd be easier to comment on what you've read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does Celery substitute Uvicorn?

No. Celery is not a replacement for Uvicorn. Uvicorn is meant to run your FastAPI application, Celery will not do that for you.

> I have read a lot about using Celery for creating a queu for FastAPI. However, you can manage a queue in FastAPI without using Celery. What's better? and why?

I guess you mean the [BackgroundTasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) here, but that is not a replacement for Celery. FastAPI BackgroundTasks are meant to execute simple tasks (and not CPU bound related tasks).

Answering the question, ideally, you'd have to start both services: Uvicorn, and Celery. You can see an example on how to do it [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/tree/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/backend).

Not that it matters much here, but I'm one of the Uvicorn maintainers.

Comment: Hard agree on this. They would work hand-in-hand. Instead of using celery consider redis-queue or rq for short for lighter ETL type things that dont need the extra framing of celery.